# Spark is inventing his own AWS secretKey

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, http-status-code-403, access-keys

I'm trying to read a s3 bucket from Spark and up until today Spark always complain that the request return 403

```
hadoopConf = spark_context._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.access.key", "ACCESSKEY")
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", "SECRETKEY")
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
logs = spark_context.textFile("s3a://mybucket/logs/*)
```

Spark was saying .... Invalid Access key [ACCESSKEY]

However with the same ACCESSKEY and SECRETKEY this was working with aws-cli

```
aws s3 ls mybucket/logs/
```

and in python boto3 this was working

```
resource = boto3.resource("s3", region_name="us-east-1")
resource.Object("mybucket", "logs/text.py") \
            .put(Body=open("text.py", "rb"),ContentType="text/x-py")
```

so my credentials ARE invalid and the problem is definitely something with Spark..

Today I decided to turn on the "DEBUG" log for the entire spark and to my suprise... Spark is NOT using the [SECRETKEY] I have provided but instead... add a random one???

17/03/08 10:40:04 DEBUG request: Sending Request: HEAD https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com / Headers: (Authorization: AWS ACCESSKEY:**[RANDON-SECRET-KEY]**, User-Agent: aws-sdk-java/1.7.4 Mac_OS_X/10.11.6 Java_HotSpot(TM)_64-Bit_Server_VM/25.65-b01/1.8.0_65, Date: Wed, 08 Mar 2017 10:40:04 GMT, Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8, )

This is why it still return 403! Spark is not using the key I provide with fs.s3a.secret.key but instead invent a random one??

For the record I'm running this locally on my machine (OSX) with this command

```
spark-submit --packages com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-pom:1.11.98,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.3 test.py
```

Could some one enlighten me on this?

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this question that worked ?

Comment: Nop, I never find out where these secret keys were getting generated from

Answer (score 2):

(updated as my original one was downvoted as clearly considered unacceptable)

The AWS auth protocol doesn't send your secret over the wire. It signs the message. That's why what you see isn't what you passed in.

For further information, please reread.

Comment: "For the record I'm running this locally on my machine (OSX) with this command"
As explained im running this locally with apache-spark binnaries

Comment: I've tried to be helpful as I can as the person who has been working full time on S3A development for 12 months. First, As stated, you are using a different AWS SDK. Fix. Second, Spark propagates env vars. Unset. Then try to get the `hadoop fs -ls s3a://mybucket/`  command working before looking at in-cluster. Then look at spark-defaults and core-site.xml to see what's happening. Finally, embrace the logs and the debuggers.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue. Requests that were using valid AWS credentials returned a 403 Forbidden, but only on certain machines. Eventually I found out that the system time on those particular machines were 10 minutes behind. Synchronizing the system clock solved the problem.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

It is very intriguing this random passkey. Maybe AWS SDK is getting the  password from OS environment.

In hadoop 2.8, the default AWS provider chain shows the following list of providers:

```
BasicAWSCredentialsProvider EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider SharedInstanceProfileCredentialsProvider
```

Order, of course, matters! the AWSCredentialProviderChain, get the first keys from the first provider that provides that information.

```
            if (credentials.getAWSAccessKeyId() != null &&
                credentials.getAWSSecretKey() != null) {
                log.debug("Loading credentials from " + provider.toString());
                lastUsedProvider = provider;
                return credentials;
            }
```

See the code in ["GrepCode for AWSCredentialProviderChain"](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk/1.8.1/com/amazonaws/auth/AWSCredentialsProviderChain.java).

I face similar problem using profile credentials. SDK was ignoring the credentials inside  ~/.aws/credentials (as good practice, I encourage you to not store credentials inside the program in any way).

My solution...

**Set the credentials provider to use ProfileCredentialsProvider**

```
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com") # yes, I am using central eu server.
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider', 'com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider')
```

Comment: spark-submit will pick up the env vars from the client if set...that could be how things get in. Regarding the fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider : that's a Hadoop 2.8 feature only: anyone trying to use it with the Hadoop 2.7 JARs will be disappointed. They should try unsetting the env vars before submitting work

Comment: for the record, it was a random key everytime (never the same)

Answer (score 0):

Folks, go for the IAM configuration based on Roles ... that will open up S3 access policies that should be added to the EMR default one.

Comment: Go luck doing that localy on a local spark cluster :)